How to make \comment commands from tcolorbox and changes usable together?
Both tcolorbox and changes provide \comment.
Is there a better and more robust solution than the one below?
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\let\comment\tcbcomment
\usepackage{changes}


If changes is loaded first, comment from tcb shadows comment from changes.

tcolorbox (verbatim) defines comment as an environment.  changes defines \comment as a command with an argument (similar to marginnotes).  You will have to rename one or the other.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\let\cmdcomment=\comment

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\let\tcbcomment=\comment
\let\endtcbcomment=\endcomment
\let\comment=\cmdcomment

\begin{document}

Above.
\comment{This is another test}

\begin{tcbcomment}
This is a test.
\end{tcbcomment}

Below.

\end{document}

